# Divs only appear after lifting finger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I am using bootstrap 3 and testing my webapp on mobile safari browser, I have have noticed that when scrolling (holding down finger and sliding up/down), if i during the scroll uncover a new div element, it won't be visible until i lift the finger

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: This may have changed but I think Twitter Bootstrap does not support touch events on its own so your code is responding to a plain old "mouseUp()" instead of a "touch()."  You will need to add a touch library like fastClick.js or use jQuery touch events to gain this functionality.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537260/recommended-way-to-enable-touch-events-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Twitter Bootstrap does not support touch events on its own so your code is responding to a plain old "mouseUp()" instead of a "touch()." You will need to add a touch library like fastClick.js or use jQuery touch events to gain this functionality. See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537260/) for more detail.